# How to do SQL Server date formatting

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, regexp-replace

I am preparing a query on sql server. But I'm stuck with the date format.
I want the date format to be at the bottom. If there are letters in it, I don't want it to appear. The ISDATE command only accepts the EN date format.
I want to write it as digit2/digit2/digit4 like alt.

```
SELECT TOP 4  * FROM A AS T WHERE 1 = 1 AND ISNUMERIC(T.Id) = 1


11111111111 FIRSTNAME LASTNAME 19.10.1965
11111111111 FIRSTNAME LASTNAME 15.8.1980
11111111111 FIRSTNAME LASTNAME 12.8.2015
11111111111 FIRSTNAME LASTNAME 3.3.1967
```

Comment: Formatting of dates should be done in the presentation layer, *not* to SQL Layer. Also, don't use `ISNUMERIC`, it is *not* a reliable function. Use `TRY_CONVERT` instead, or (better yet) if you `ID` column is *meant* to be numerical then actually store it in a numerical data type.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but they gave the data as a string, and I want to save the data more properly to convert it to date type.

Comment: So you're not asking about formatting at all, and actually asking how to convert that value *to* a `date`? Have you looked at `CONVERT` and/or `TRY_CONVERT`?

Comment: It might sound like that.  I looked but I couldn't find any information about the TURKEY date format. Just PARSE('05.12.2016' AS date USING 'tr-TR') It gives an error when an inappropriate date comes, I want it not to include that result in the list without giving an error.

Comment: What was wrong with the style code `104`?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/tUlHraHUemqi The ISDATE function sometimes returns false but the date is correct because it considers the EN date format

Comment: Because `ISDATE` is almost as unreliable as `ISNUMERIC`. This is why I have both recommend and asked multiple times why you aren't using `TRY_CONVERT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ISDATE` is the wrong approach here because it only supports a narrow range of formats and relies on the regional/language settings of the caller, e.g.:

```
SELECT ISDATE('19.10.1965'), -- 0
       ISDATE('10.19.1965'); -- 1

SET LANGUAGE Türkçe;

SELECT ISDATE('19.10.1965'), -- 1
       ISDATE('10.19.1965'); -- 0
```

Trying to match a pattern like digit2/digit2/digit4 is also the wrong approach, since it will allow "dates" like `31/02/3456` and `99/99/0000`.

Try:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date, '19.10.1965', 104);
```

As a filter:

```
... WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date, date_column, 104) IS NOT NULL;
```

Also I would stay away from `PARSE`/`TRY_PARSE`/`FORMAT` as the CLR overhead can be substantial.

Comment: Thank you this is a great answer. There are sometimes letters between the date data because the data is corrupt, how can I separate them?

Comment: @BarışSakızlı You need to show some examples.

Comment: Rather than  SET LANGUAGE, a more readable option would be Set DateFormat DMY

Comment: @John I used that because the OP mentioned Turkish, but also because it's much more likely an end user has their own language set than an explicit dateformat. Also, it's merely an example of how `ISDATE()` is unreliable, not a recommendation of what to use.